Shared Folders: "Destination folder access denied" when access from father folder (windows server 2019)
I have two users, "CL1" and "CL2," belong to "CL" group. To share data within the group CL, everyone can view each other's data but only modify their own folders.
On the server, I created the "Depart1" folder, contains 2 subfolders: "Folder1" and "Folder2." Then config (both sharing and NTFS permissions) as follows:
Depart1:

Administrators - Full Control
SYSTEM - Full Control
Authenticated Users - List Folder Contents

Folder1:

User CL1 - Modify

Folder2:

User CL2 - Modify

I did follows this answer serverfault.com/a/111643 from Evan Anderson (thank you).
The issue is when user CL1 maps the shared folder Depart1 and then access Folder1, he's not allowed to create a new folder or upload files. Only when CL1 maps "Folder1" directly, he's able to modify it.
I’m not sure if I'm missing something, or if CL1 actually has to map 2 separate shared folders to upload files and browse others' files?
UPDATE: I managed to fix it after change sharing permittions of "Depart1" to Modify (NTFS is still Read). No longer need to share subfolders.
